# Can I write this code without using file stream

Tags: c, linux

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Read characters from the pipe and echo them to stdout. */

void read_from_pipe (int file)
{
  FILE *stream;
  int c;
  stream = fdopen (file, "r");
  while ((c = fgetc (stream)) != EOF)
    putchar (c);
  fclose (stream);
}

/* Write some random text to the pipe. */

void write_to_pipe (int file)
{
  FILE *stream;
  stream = fdopen (file, "w");
  fprintf (stream, "Hello from Parent!\n");
  fclose (stream);
}

int main (void)
{
  int pid;
  int mypipe[2];

  /* Create the pipe. */
  if (pipe (mypipe))
    {
      printf("Pipe failed.\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

  /* Create the child process. */
  pid = fork ();
  if (pid == 0)
    {
      /* This is the child process.
         Close other end first. */
      close (mypipe[1]);
      read_from_pipe (mypipe[0]);
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
  else if (pid < 0)
    {
      /* The fork failed. */
      printf ("Fork failed.\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  else
    {
      /* This is the parent process.
         Close other end first. */
      close (mypipe[0]);
      write_to_pipe (mypipe[1]);
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

I want to write simple program to do this task:

- Parent process creates a pipe using the pipe() system call.
- Parent process creates a child process.
- Parent process sends a message "Hello from Parent" to the child.
- Child process prints the message to the screen.

This code creates File stream. I can't understand  why. Without file stream can I do this thing..?

Comment: If you don't understand why this code uses file streams (that is, you have an idea how to do the same without them), why don't you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [File descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor).

Basically, when you call `pipe()`, the operating system prepares two file descriptors and writes their "names" to the argument (`mypipe` in this case).

You can use these file descriptors without opening any file streams by using the standard operating system calls: `write()`, `read()`, `close()`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This answer may be helpful for a future Googler.

I guess this is what you are looking for.
Here is what I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){     
     int p, f;  
     int rw_setup[2];   
     char message[20];      
     p = pipe(rw_setup);    
     if(p < 0){         
        printf("An error occured. Could not create the pipe.");  
        _exit(1);   
     }      
     f = fork();    
     if(f > 0){
        write(rw_setup[1], "Hello from Parent", 18);    
     }  
     else if(f == 0){       
        read(rw_setup[0],message,18);       
        printf("%s %d\n", message, r_return);   
     }  
     else{      
        printf("Could not create the child process");   
     }      
     return 0;

}
```

To create child process we use fork(). fork() returns :

- <0 fail to create child (new) process
- =0 for child process
- >0 i.e process ID of the child process to the parent process. When >0 parent process will execute.

pipe() is used for passing information from one process to another. pipe() is unidirectional therefore, for two-way communication between processes, two pipes can be set up, one for each direction.

You can read more [details](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-demonstrate-fork-and-pipe/) here.